# Creating index and optimizing MySql Query to get faster results in php

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I am working in a MySql, I have two tables **one is for music_table** with 24666 records, 30 columns  and **another lookup table called genre_master** with just 9 records, cant say it was a huge table, i want to load the songs based on the genre it takes huge time to load from the database and the structure is

***genre_master*** table

```
--------------------
gnre_id | gnre_name
--------------------
    1   |    Rock
    2   |    Pop
    3   |    Workship
```

**music_table** table

---

```
song_id | GENRE | album | etc
-----------------------------
    1   |  2    | a     |
    2   |  3    | b     |
    3   |  4    | c     |
```

**my php code is like**

```
foreach ($genre_master as $genre) {
  $Songs=GetLatestSongs($genre->gnre_id);
          foreach ($Songs as $music) {
                 <span><?php echo lchar($music->TITLE,22); ?></span>   
          }
}
```

**and my sql query is**

```
function GetLatestSongs($genre_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $gnre_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM ciam_rddm_music where GENRE= '".$genre_id."'"); 
    if(!$gnre_count > 0){
        $genre_id= 6;
    }
    $songs = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT song_id, LENGTH, TITLE, COMPOSER, ORIGIN_DATETIME, album_id from ciam_rddm_music 
        FORCE INDEX (idx_genre)
        WHERE GENRE='".$genre_id."' 
        ORDER BY ORIGIN_DATETIME DESC
        LIMIT 10");
    return $songs;
}
```

it takes more than 3-5 minutes to load the page if i remove the `GetLatestSongs($genre_id)` line i loads within 10 seconds i have created index on the GENRE column on the music_table and used force index on the search query still it was loading too slow where i made the mistake? is there any way to speed up loading the query and the indexes where

```
        Keyname     Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        PRIMARY     BTREE   Yes     No      song_id  24666        A         No  
        idx_genre   BTREE   No      No      GENRE    94           A         Yes
```

Comment: You order by `ORIGIN_DATETIME` so that column should have an index.

Comment: Why do you do a `count(*)` first?  The less SQL statements you run the better.